# Removing File Services Role From A Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, file-server

Someone in my office install the file service role on the domain controller, while trying to remove the role for the domain controller.

I get the message that I have to remove the active directory service before I can remove the file server role.

How can I remove this role without affecting the Active Directory?

Comment: First of all, what access level do the other staff have? To perform such an install would require administrative rights. If so, you need to change them so just users, not admins. You could disable the feature.

Comment: The staff had administrative rights, but that have been changed to plain users. The issue now is removing the file service role without losing the domain controller content.

Comment: This question is at risk of being closed, if you re-word it so that it's more generally useful, and provide more detail (exactly error message, screenshots, what steps you're taking) so that people searching later for the same issue find it, it might survive.

Answer (score 9):

You can't remove the file service from the server. It is required by AD to share configuration with all member computers.  It wasn't installed by a user, it was setup as part of the AD configuration process.  Stop trying to remove it, it is supposed to be there!

If someone setup shares you were not expecting, that is a different story.  You should remove those and change user roles as you mention.  Just make sure you don't delete any of the AD shares.

Lastly, buy an Active Directory book and learn how to properly administer an AD environment!

Comment: In deed can confirm that Windows Server 2012 R2 DC has by default installs File and Storage Services role with the following subcomponents of this role: File Server, Storage Services. So indeed no need to delete them on DC, they are required for your SYSVOL and NETLOGON shares.